# LINQ C# Selecting characters from string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string that I convert to a char array and then I use LINQ to select the different characters inside the char array and then order them by Descending but only catch the characters, not the punctuation marks etc...

Here is the code:

```
string inputString = "The black, and, white cat";
var something = inputString.ToCharArray();
var txtEntitites = something.GroupBy(c => c)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                   .Where(e => Char.IsLetter(e)).Select(t=> t.Key);
```

And the error message I get:

- Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `char.IsLetter(char)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)
- Error CS1503: Argument '#1' cannot convert 'System.Linq.IGrouping<char,char>' expression to type `char' (CS1503)

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: `Char.IsLetter(e.Key)` I Just got this working messing around in VSCode https://gist.github.com/Lewiscowles1986/30d774133f619a9010ad0f17f8861cd0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
string inputString = "The black, and, white cat"; 
var something = inputString.ToCharArray();  
var txtEntitites = something.GroupBy(c => c)
                            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                            .Where(e => Char.IsLetter(e.Key))
                            .Select(t=> t.Key);
```

Note the `Char.IsLetter(e.Key))`

Another idea is to rearrange your query:

```
var inputString = "The black, and, white cat"; 
var txtEntitites = inputString.GroupBy(c => c)
                              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                              .Select(t=> t.Key)
                              .Where(e => Char.IsLetter(e));
```

Also note you don't need the call to `inputString.ToCharArray()` since `String` is already an `IEnumerable<Char>`.

Comment: Thank you :) And thank you for not complaining or marking me down for asking a question ha!

Comment: Your question was short, concise and gave good details of the error message so I gave it a vote up :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your where clause, `e` in that context is your grouping, not the character.  If you want to check if the character is a letter, you should be testing your key.

```
//...
.Where(g => Char.IsLetter(g.Key))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<char> charArray = (
      from c in inputString
      where c >= 'A' && c <= 'z'
      orderby c
      select c
   ).Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
string inputString = "The black, and, white cat";
var something = inputString.ToCharArray();
var txtEntitites = something.Where(e => Char.IsLetter(e))
                   .GroupBy(c => c)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(t=> t.Key);
```